# How to get the line count of content of the Spark TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I want to get the line count of the spark text area content.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this site you can find a working example : http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/08/determining-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea-control-in-flex/

and the same is explained here: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/13/determining-the-number-of-lines-in-a-spark-richeditabletext-control-in-flex-4/

hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

A way to read the number of lines for a Spark Label is to import the **mx_internal** namespace like

```
use namespace mx_internal;
```

and then access the **textLines** property of the label like the following:

```
var numLines : int = myLabel.mx_internal::textLines.length;
```